# Hyperledger Fabric 1.4 support for golang 1.12.x?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Using HLF 1.4 and *trying* to conform to documentation, however, docs indicate that go 1.11.x MUST be installed -- is there not support for go 1.12.7? If not, when? 1.11.x is considered "archived".

Please advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently running fabric 1.4.3 with go version 1.13.5 so it seems that the docs are out of date